# .htaccess with 1 or 2 GET parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to have few elements in my `.htaccess`:

- I want all the PHP files to work by accessing `/index` without having to put `.php` after.

I used:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

- I have an `index.php` page that sometimes has 1 GET parameter and sometimes 2:

  - www.domain.com/?first=data
  - www.domain.com/?first=data&second=data2

I used:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But it's only working if I have the 2 elements; if I use a link with just the first parameter, I get an error page.

How can i solve it ?

Comment: for #2, have a look at `[QSA]`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(member)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=member&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&saction=$2&sid=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?action=details&id=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4 [NC,L]
```